# jQuery DataTable add new row with new API

Tags: datatables

I tried to add a new row with new `jQuery DataTable API` used by this example: http://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html, but have no idea why it's not working.

Here is a jsfiddle example showing what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/cvLRg/

The error I am getting: `TypeError: row is undefined`

P.S.: DataTables Version 1.10.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call the `add` method without giving it the data for the new row. See this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvLRg/1/).

```
employersTable.row.add( [
        'added row',
        'Test 2',
        123,
        '2014-05-09',
        'No',
        'blub'
    ] ).draw();
```